# Not able to created ReflectedWorkItemId field for all work item types

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to use nkdagility tool for migration.
As mentioned in the docs , I am trying to create 'ReflectedWorkItemId' field for all work item types.
After I created it for one workitem type say for 'Bug' , I am not able to create a new field with same name for another work item type say 'Epic'
It throws error "The field name is already used.
Please help

It should allow me to create the field with same name for different work item type as mentioned in the document

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that we need to create a new field only for one work item type and for other work item types we need to use "Use existing field" option while creating new field.